# Multithreaded Algorithm Logic

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading, algorithm

I'm trying to loop over a very large array for the longest streak of occurrences using multiple threads. I'm not exactly sure how to split up the work per thread. I had previously calculated the total by splitting the array by the number of threads

```
size/threads
```

and looped over the smaller blocks counting occurrences and summing.

The problem here is that with the array split into blocks, my guess is that it will mess up the streaks or that it might be a lot of work connecting threads if I counted them separately.

Can anyone suggest a solution? I'm programming in Java but tagged the other languages as this is a logic question and not language specific

edit: This is the code without concurrency

```
public void countStreaks()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < number_of_teams; i++)
    {
        int current_streak = 0;
        highest_streak_per_team[i] = 0;

        for(int j = 0; j < number_of_matches; j++)
        {
            if(home_away_winner[j][0] == i || home_away_winner[j][1] == i)
            {
                if(home_away_winner[j][2] == i)
                {
                    current_streak++;
                }
                else
                {
                    if(highest_streak_per_team[i] < current_streak)
                    {
                        highest_streak_per_team[i] = current_streak;
                    }
                    current_streak = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

}

edit2: I would prefer logic solutions than a working/code solution

Answer (score 0):

Split the array at the end of a streak.

If you plan on splitting at `i`, check that `a[i]` and `a[i+1]` are 2 different sequences. If they belong the same sequanece, try with `i = i+1` until you reach the end of a streak.

Answer (score 0):

Have each thread produce an object that contains six pieces of information:

- The length and team of the streak that starts at the first element in the range
- The length and team of the streak that ends at the last element the range (might be the same as the first length, if the entire range is one streak)
- The length and team of the longest streak in the range (might be the same as either or both of the above)

When all threads have finished, iterate over all these objects (in the sequence that corresponds to the order of the ranges). If the team of the ending streak of one range is the same as the team of the starting streak in the next range, you know that they can be combined into one streak, and if the starting streak's length is equal to the range length, you know that it might be combined with the starting streak in the next range, and so on.